# how to make a visible <div> and not blocker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html code and its.

> `<input type="submit" class="sub" /><div class="img"></div>`

Now the CSS code is

> .img{backgound: url(image.png);height:10px;width:10px;}

img class position (located) on the submit. now when i try to click the submit (the img class is over it). it not clicked because of the img class.

now i want to make the div class is visible but at the same time it not blocks when i click the submit.

> I dont want to use background for the submit, because im already using it on the submit with another image.

i wish that you understand me.

and im sorry for my english ...

Thanks,

Comment: why do you not use an input of the type image? <input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" />

Answer (score 1):

assuming ur code looks like

```
<form id="myform" action="myaction.php">
...
<input type="submit" class="sub" /><div class="img"></div>
...
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#myform .img').click(function(){
   $('#myform').trigger('submit');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('.img').click(function(){$(this.parentNode).click();});
```

Comment: The `.img` element is not a child of the element in question, so `parentNode` will not refer to the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.img').click(function() {
        $(this).prev('input.sub:submit').trigger('click');
    }); 

    // click event for submit

    $('input.sub:submit').click(function() { 

        // here goes you submit actions

        alert('submit');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to have an img on top of a submit, and make it so that when you click that img, the form is still submitted? If so, then you're probably better off using JavaScript. Here's a sample of what it'd look like with jQuery:

```
$('.img').click(function() {
        $('.img').siblings('[type=submit]').click();
});
```

This makes it so that when you click the image, it will act as if you clicked the submit button too.

On that note, there must be a better way to do this (i.e. without JavaScript and extra divs), but since I don't know much about your problem, I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a button with already a background image on it , 
and you want that when you press the div above - the button will also be pressed youll need to do this :

on the div element you put:

```
onclick='simulateButtonPress();'
```

and in js : **(via Jquery)**

```
function simulateButtonPress()
{
    $("#btnId").trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    return true;
});
```